# Need to edit a file with root permissions

Tags: python, python-2.7, unix, root

As part of an automation requirement, I need to edit eth4 (ethernet setting) file from my python script. I am not running as a root user, but editing this file requires root permission. Can this be done.
Also I am using python 2.7 since this code is run from Squish 6.3 for atomating a JAVA swing application which comes with default python 2.7

I havn't yet tried anything yet, since I am not sure of this.

The final requirement is that we have to add one line at the end of the file and later need to remove the same line from this file.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which are the eth4 file permissions? Output of `ls -l eth4`

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to call out to a program like `sudo`.

You can either invoke the script as root using sudo, or have the script call sudo as part of a pipe (see https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html).

You can even get your script to detect that it hasn't run as root and run itself as root using sudo and then do what your script needs to do.

Comment: Will it work on windows? I think NO! But you are right bc he mentioned unix in his tag

Comment: @Code_10 i did not quite understand what are you saying. is there a root user on windows? officially called the root? (you edited the comment while i am writing this...)

Comment: @Code_10 Your Windows has a 'root' account and a network configuration file?

Comment: This is not my question! Secondly, my only concern was that the mentioned solution will work on windows? I think NO because 'sudo' only works on linux. This solution won't work on cross platform. Did you get my point?